# How to change jQuery terminal --char-width

Tags: jquery, css, fonts, jquery-terminal

I am using jQuery Terminal 2.4.1. In Chrome the Terminal allows the user to type characters only half of terminal width and it wraps. Firefox it works fine.

The only difference I am seeing is `--char-width` is `7` in FF and `12.7344` in Chrome. Is it calculating the line wrap width wrongly and getting truncated half?

If I set width like below, it wraps properly and occupying full window width

```
Ext.getElementById('terminalContainer').style.width = "180%";
terminal.resize();
```

However then the vertical scroll bar is hidden.

How can I set `--char-width` in Chrome?

Comment: There is [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/jcubic/jquery.terminal/issues/504) if you can create demo that would be awesome, and don't forget to write on what OS and what version of Chrome, you have the issue, because it works fine on GNU/Linux Chromium 73.

Comment: Chrome version 74 Windows server 2008

Comment: Hmm, I can only test on Windows 10, maybe BrowserStack have window server 2008, any special code you're using? Do you have this error in Terminal demo at https://terminal.jcubic.pl/ ?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm unable to test. BrowserStack have only windows XP, 7, 8, 8.1 and 10. But the issue must by with your code. Can you create demo that can reproduce the problem maybe codepen (fork https://codepen.io/jcubic/pen/MbVMwO) or jsFiddle?

Comment: Hi Jankiewicz,  Is there a way we can override jQuery terminal's built in function for example get_char_size(e) ?

Comment: No there are no option for that, there is only an option to set number of character per line that was added mostly for testing from NodeJS. But this must be an error in your code or in library. Please provide demo where you have this error. We will see if it's also happen on Windows 10/Chrome if not I've try to install server 2018 on VirtualBox and try to fix the issue.